# Vue3-My provide is not updated after changing the data using mounted

Tags: vue.js, data-visualization

I tried to provide my data from a parent element like below.

```
data(){
    return{
    allData:null,
    ingCollection:null,
    selectedDish:[]
    }
  },

  
  mounted(){
    Promise.all([
      d3.json('data.json'),
      d3.json('ingredientsonly.json')
    ]).then((data)=>{
      this.allData=data[0];
      this.ingCollection=data[1];
      
    })
  },
  components:{sidePanel,centerPiece},

  methods: {
    // receiveIngredients(selected){
    //   let selections = this.allData.filter(d=>{
    //     d.ingredients.includes(selected)
    //   });

    // }
  },
    provide() {
    return{
    allData:this.allData,
    ingCollection:this.ingCollection,
    selectedDish:this.selectedDish,
    receiveIngredients:this.receiveIngredients
    }
  }
```

However, after mounted lifecycle hook was run,
data is updated while provide elements were not updated.

Why is it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`provide()` is only called once at initialization, and not when there's a change to the references within.

Instead, you can `provide` an object (e.g., named `root`), and then update a property of that object in `mounted()`:

```js
export default {
  provide() {
    return {
      root: {
        allData: null,
        ingCollection: null,
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    Promise.all([
      d3.json('data.json'),
      d3.json('ingredientsonly.json')
    ]).then((data)=>{
      this.root.allData = data[0];
      this.root.ingCollection = data[1];
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a reproduction in codesandbox to help troubleshoot?